# Interactive grid removes spaces

Tags: oracle-apex

Look at the query and result generated in sqlplus :

```
SELECT 
  plan_line_id,
  LPAD (a.plan_operation || ' ' || a.plan_options,
        LENGTH (a.plan_operation || ' ' || a.plan_options) + a.plan_depth * 3
       ) OPERATION,
  a.plan_cost COST,
  output_rows "ROWS"
FROM gV$SQL_PLAN_MONITOR a
WHERE sql_id = '8gan9d0z7bzhm'
```

[image]

Looks pretty cool doesn't it   ;)

And the same result in grid report :

[image]

Apex 21 removes all spaces generated by lpad function. The same problem is with classic report and classic grid :( any idea why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use a character which can be correctly interpreted by your browser - instead of a space, use a *non-breaking space*, the `&nbsp` character.

Something like this (I'm using the `#` character in the CTE, which is then replaced by `&nbsp;`:

```
WITH
   temp
   AS
      (SELECT plan_line_id,
              LPAD (
                 a.plan_operation || ' ' || a.plan_options,
                   LENGTH (a.plan_operation || ' ' || a.plan_options)
                 + a.plan_depth * 3,
                 '#') OPERATION,                       --> here
              a.plan_cost COST,
              output_rows "ROWS"
         FROM a1_test a
        WHERE     sql_id = '9p4xcx2gd8u49')
SELECT plan_line_id,
       REPLACE (operation, '#', '&nbsp;') operation,   --> here
       cost,
       "ROWS"
  FROM temp
```

Turn "Operation" column's **Escape special characters" property OFF.

The result is then

[image]

Not as pretty as you'd want it to, but it is *better* than what you currently have.

Comment: which browser do you use?  In my  FF character &nbsp; is printed as it is :(

Comment: You'll have to turn "Operation" column's **Escape special characters" property OFF.

Comment: BINGO !   It is as pretty as I want !   Thank you Littlefoot